# Gmail App Script - Extract E-mail Content from Gmail Label Instead of Gmail Inbox

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I have an online form that sends submitted form field data to Gmail. I've been using the script below to extract the form field data into a Google Sheet. Currently, the script extracts from the inbox. I'm wondering if there is a way to adjust the script so that it looks at a Gmail label (for example: formsubmissions) instead of the inbox.

```
function parseEmailMessages(start) {

  start = start || 0;

  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(start, 100);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

    // Get the first email message of a threads
    var tmp,
      message = threads[i].getMessages()[0],
      subject = message.getSubject(),
      content = message.getPlainBody();

    // Get the plain text body of the email message
    // You may also use getRawContent() for parsing HTML

    // Implement Parsing rules using regular expressions
    if (content) {

      tmp = content.match(/First:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
      var first = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';

      tmp = content.match(/Last:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
      var last = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';

      tmp = content.match(/Title:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
      var title = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';

      tmp = content.match(/Organization:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
      var organization = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';

      tmp = content.match(/City:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
      var city = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';

      tmp = content.match(/State:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
      var state = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';

      tmp = content.match(/Country:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
      var country = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';

      tmp = content.match(/E-mail:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@_.\-]+)/);
      var email = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';

      tmp = content.match(/BLANK:\s*([\s\S]+)/);
      var blank = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1] : 'BLANK';

      sheet.appendRow([first, last, title, organization, city, state, country, email]);

    } // End if

  } // End for loop
}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking into using [GmailLabel](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-label)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve `threads` from a label of `formsubmissions` which is the label name.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as just one of them.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

From:

```
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(start, 100);
```

To:

```
var labelName = "formsubmissions"; // Please set the label name
var labels = GmailApp.getUserLabels();
var threads = [];
for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
  if (labels[i].getName() == labelName) {
    threads = labels[i].getThreads();
    break;
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- Tis modified script supposes that the script below `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();` works fine.

#### References:

- [getUserLabels()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getuserlabels)
- [getThreads()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-label#getThreads())

If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, Tanaike. I tried your modification and it worked. Many thanks!

Comment: @dlc3172 I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.